# Are the functions differentiable?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

> Are the following functions $f,g:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ differentiable? 
>   $$f(x)=x|x|$$
>   $$g(x)=\sin|x|$$

I proceded with the usual limit form to find derivative, but don't know how to apply it for piecewise functions. Please explain in simple terms.

Comment: The only place where they might not be differentiable is at $x=0$. So, investigate their behaviour there.

Comment: HINT:|x| = \left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{l}}
{x,}&{{\rm{if }}x \ge 0}\\
{ - x,}&{{\rm{if }}x < 0.}
\end{array}} \right

Answer (score 1):

Clearly  $f(x)$ is differentiable for non-zero $x$ as it is the product of differentiable functions. At $x=0$ however we have $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x} 
= \lim_{x \to 0} |x| = 0$. So the derivative exists and is $0$.

Clearly $g(x)$ is differentiable for non zero $x$ as it is the composition of differentiable functions. At $x=0$ we have $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin |x|}{x}$. Look at the right and left limits of this, are they the same? Can the limit exist?

Answer (score 1):

1.

You have $x^2, x>0$ and $-x^2,x<0$. At zero, both derivatives are zero, and each pieces are differentiable, hence the function is differentiable.

2.

You have $\text{sin}(x),x>o$ and $-\text{sin}(x),x<0$. At zero, from these, $\text{cos}(x)=1$, and $-\text{cos}(x)=-1$. Hence you have two values for the derivative, hence the function is not differentiable.

Comment: So we have to check derivative of each part seperately in first case?

Comment: Yes in both....

Answer (score 0):

The function $f(x)$ is differentiable for all $x\in\mathbb R$. We have
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
  x^2 \quad \ \ \  \mbox{ for } x\ge0, \\
-x^2 \quad \mbox{ for } x\le0, 
\end{cases}
$$
and so $f'(0)=0$.

The function $g(x)$ is not differentiable at $x=0$:
$$
g(x) = \sin|x| = \begin{cases}
x + O(x^3) \quad \ \ \  \mbox{ for } x\to0, \ \ x\ge0, \\
-x + O(x^3) \quad   \mbox{ for } x\to0, \ \ x\le0; 
\end{cases}
$$
therefore the derivative $g'(x)$ does not exist at $x=0$.

Answer (score 0):

If $x\neq0$ then $f$ is differentiable. 
Since $$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow0^+}f'(x)=\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow0^+}2x=0$$ and
 $$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow0^-}f'(x)=\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow0^-}(-2x)=0,$$
we see that $f$ is differentiable.

In anther hand $g$ is not differentiable function.

Indeed, 
$$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow0^+}g'(x)=\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow0^+}\cos{x}=1,$$ 
but 
$$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow0^-}g'(x)=\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow0^-}(-\cos{x})=-1.$$